# How can I pass varargs to a @GET request

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions, query-string

I'm trying to set up a service that allows uses to retrieve multiple entries from a database.  To allow users to specify the entries they want to see, I'm passing varargs for the id numbers:

```
public Person getPersons(int... ids) {
    //my code here
}
```

How can I set this up to work with either @QueryParam or @FormParam, though?  I've tried setting it up like such:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/search")
public Person getPersons(@QueryParam("id") int... ids) {
    //my code here
}
```

So, if id numbers 1 and 5 are in the parameters, the entries for those particlar profiles will be returned.

However, this only errors for the ids variable, with the following notice:

```
Checks types of parameters annotated @PathParam, @QueryParam, etc. The type of the annotated parameter, field or property must either:
Be a primitive type.
Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument.
Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String)).
Have a registered implementation of ParamConverterProvider JAX-RS extension SPI that returns a ParamConverter instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type.
Be List<T>, Set<T> or SortedSet<T>, where T satisfies 2, 3 or 4 above. The resulting collection is read-only.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the same query param multiple times with different values

```
id=1&id=2&id=3
```

Then you can read the list of ID's in a array:

```
public Response receiveListOfID(@QueryParam("id") final List<String> idList) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: This is not Spring, so `RequestParam` is not available